# how to fetch data from array?

Tags: iphone, nsarray, uilabel

I have created one `NSarray`, Now I want to display it's data in labels according to their index.

But not want to display them in table view cell.
I want to display them in simple labels.

Comment: So where is the problem?

Comment: i want to know how can i display data of array using their index in label....you got that

Comment: Hope you got the solution now..Spend some time with reading-- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html

Comment: also this- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i=0; i<[yourArr count]; i++) {
    yourLblObject.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[yourArr objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

Comment: when i am doing this way is giving object address like the -<pillbox: 0x5e1e090> .......but i want to show string in label...

Comment: Can you tell me what is in your array?

Answer (score 1):

use this code I think this will be helpful for you

```
 -(void)viewdidload
   {
 playerScores = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"11",@"12",@"13",@"14",@"15",@"16",@"17",@"18",nil] retain];
 CGFloat y = 20;
for (int i = 0;i<[playerScores count];i++) {
    myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, y, 60, 60)];
    myLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    [myLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:35]];
    NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:[playerScores objectAtIndex:i]];
    [myLabel setText:text];

    [yardsScrollView addSubview:myLabel];
    [myLabel release];
    y = y+125;
}


 }
```

Comment: @virendra if You got the answer inform us if not then also so We can try to solve your problem.Thanks

Comment: ok......it is giving some waring Format not a string literal and no format arguments....

Comment: in this line -NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:[arrStudents objectAtIndex:i]];

Comment: Which side you want your label y axis or x axis if you want on y then use y instant of x it will surely work for you because I am using same code for my apps.its work fine you try again and tell me exact error.I ll try to help you

Comment: do one this first create one mutable array add some object in that array and then pass that array in this text and above in for loop also call the same array.

Comment: i want to show lable in upper left corner that is not a problem....ok let me try this ......